# Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types

Tags: linq-to-entities

When I run the following query(asp.net in VB), I get "Unable to cast the type 'System.String' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types." error.  I have tried several reditions of the query, but get the error.

I think it has something to do with the joins and the select. Any ideas?

*From comment*

```
query = (from p in context.Clients 
                join j in context.Loans on p.Number equals j.ClientNum 
                join lb in context.LIBORs on lb.LoanNum equals j.LoanNum 
                join w in context.WUserIDs on w.RegionNum equals j.RegionNum 
                join f in context.FASBs on f.LoanNum equals j.LoanNum 
         select j.RateType, j.LoanNum, lb, w, f).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things:
1. With join condition specify the first variable and then the second.
2. Select a single object.

```
var query = (from p in context.Clients 
                join j in context.Loans on p.Number equals j.ClientNum 
                join lb in context.LIBORs on j.LoanNum equals lb.LoanNum
                join w in context.WUserIDs on j.RegionNum equals w.RegionNum
                join f in context.FASBs on j.LoanNum equals f.LoanNum
         select new { j.RateType, j.LoanNum, lb, w, f}).ToList();
```